# Can continually assigning a variable in a shell script cause a memory leak?

Tags: shell-script, cron, memory

I've written a short script to copy Apache's server status to a log:

```
#Save date and time to a variable
dt=$(date)

#Echo date and time to the log file as it's not included in server-status
echo "Time :" $dt >> /var/logs/server-status.log

#Grab machine readable server-status and add it to the log
curl localhost/server-status?auto >> /var/logs/server-status.log
```

I'm running it every five minutes from a cron job in /var/spool/cron/root but taking a look at the sysstat logs it seems to be using progressively more memory:

[image]

So my question is: Could I be causing a memory leak by continually writing to this variable?

Do I need to kill it after the script is run?

Comment: It shouldn't. Can you check if you have other processes consuming a lot of memory? `ps -ef` or `top` may help.

Comment: It is very unlikely that this script is anything to do with your memory issue.

Comment: But why are you continually writing to the variable? You're piping just piping it into a file after all, right? I might have missed something but: `date >file` Or, with echo: `echo "Time: $(date)" >>file`

Comment: @mikeserv, don't need echo even: `date "+Time: %c" >> file`

Comment: That script you posted is using output redirection, so the content isn't being held in memory at all. Plus I'm assuming that's the whole script, and it exits after completing (cron launches a new one each time). The critical question, does that graph you included cache as part of "memory used", or is that non-cache memory used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: Yes, it can.  *Provided there is a bug in the script interpreter*.

But, in your code you are not doing anything funny so if you are using stable version of the shell, it's almost 100% sure your problem is somewhere else.